# How to use the osd, equ.traineddata and other trained data files ( bengali, hindi) with pytesseract (Commands and where to put eq.traineddata)

Tags: ubuntu, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want the tesseract engine to use `eq.traineddata` to work on some mathematics as well as Bengali , Hindi  texts. When I go to `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata`, I see only a bunch of `*.traineddata` files. Checking the [official documentation](/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata), I find the links to these data files. I have downloaded `osd.traineddata` and all other files given in [tessdata link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) at the github.

Now What do I have to do?? Where do I have to put these files and then which command will enable these languages?

I am using `Ubuntu 18` and `Conda` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your *.traineddata files to /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata. During running tesseract you can pass the traineddata using -l param.

E.g) tesseract inputpath output -l osd